# Get overall sum of all databases size in a SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to calculate how much space my databases are using in a server. I could use `sp_spacefiles` or query `sys.databases` table but that would give me separate results for each database and I would have to copy that into an excel sheet and calculate the sum from there.

Is there a direct way of doing it in T-SQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can query [`master.sys.master_files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186782.aspx):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(SUM(size * 8.00) / 1024.00 / 1024.00)) As UsedSpace
FROM master.sys.master_files
```

This will give you a total in GB.

`Sys.Master_files` is a server-wide view that lists every file in every DB.  It's available from SQL Server 2005 onward.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I guess for SQL Server 2000 I will have to use the code @jennifer-s has provided, right?

Comment: Thank you. Simple and useful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer I found on SQLServerCentral.com.  There are a couple different scripts provided by different users on this page.. Perhaps one of them would provide what you're looking for.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic670489-146-1.aspx

Here is one of the scripts from MANU-J:

```
Create TABLE #db_file_information( 
fileid integer
, theFileGroup integer
, Total_Extents integer
, Used_Extents integer
, db varchar(30)
, file_Path_name varchar(300))

-- Get the size of the datafiles

insert into #db_file_information 
( fileid 
, theFileGroup 
, Total_Extents 
, Used_Extents 
, db 
, file_Path_name )
exec sp_MSForEachDB 'Use ?; DBCC showfilestats'

-- add two columns to the temp table

alter table #db_file_information add PercentFree as 
((Total_Extents-Used_Extents)*100/(Total_extents))

alter table #db_file_information add TotalSpace_MB as 
((Total_Extents*64)/1024)

alter table #db_file_information add UsedSpace_MB as 
((Used_Extents*64)/1024)

alter table #db_file_information add FreeSpace_MB as 
((Total_Extents*64)/1024-(Used_Extents*64)/1024)

select * from #db_file_information

drop table #db_file_information
```

Comment: We generally discourage link-only answers since if the link dies the answer is useless.  Please put an excerpt or some examples in the text of your answer.

Comment: Sorry.  Edited to include one of the scripts.

Comment: Please be wary of sp_MSforeachdb; it does not always run for all databases (see my comments about it here https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx). I wrote a replacement you are welcome to copy from here: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=2201

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs per-file calculation:

```
select physical_name, size,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(size * 8.00) / 1024.00) As UsedSpace
from master.sys.master_files
order by physical_name
```

The results are in MBytes